# Transparent/ invisible window (bug/issue and not visual effect)

Tags: macos

Windows would go transparent, as in the attached screenshot, at random. This has been happening for months. Finder is the most frequent window that would go transparent, second is safari. But basically any app can go transparent, including Eclipse in the screenshot.

This usually happens alongside slowing down of the performance of the entire mac. Even the mouse pointer and the cursor blink would become so sluggish. Is this potentially an issue caused by low spare ram memory or gpu memory? Sometimes the app would also crash in a few moments; sometimes the app would still be running this way forever until I close it.

The only way to get around this is to restart my computer. But this is extremely inconvenient as it happens on average once a day.

[image: transparent window in yosemite]

Comment: I'd guess you're running critically low on RAM or swap space. Can you get pics of Activity Monitor, RAM & CPU usage screens?

Comment: I dont have enough reputation to add more photos, but my memory usage is 1.38GB out of 8GB available.There are around 80% idle CPU usage as well.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am having this exact issue right now :(